# Connect to a WebService through VPN in Linux

Tags: php, vpn, web-services

I have been given a remote `WS.` But the provider told me that I can connect to their `WS` only through a `VPN/IPsec`.

How can I do that?
The scenario is this:

[user] --- > [My Firewall] -->[My Web Server] ---->Internet ----> [Their VPN] --->[Their Web Server]

My users land on my website; they order some service; my linux server start a vpn connection towards the remote WS provider;my server start the WS calls.

**[EDIT]**

After some reflections, I thought to this solution.
First, install ipsec OpenSwan on my web server and create a new virtual interface with a `virtual IP`. Then, create a virtual `subdomain` on my webserver. When a have to connect to the remote WS, my Apache Web server will proxy requests to the virtual `subdomain`. Does this solution make a sense?

Comment: My first instinct is to simply make the VPN/IPsec connection persistent and not on demand - Problem solved.

Comment: How? Can you give me some pointers?

Comment: http://xmodulo.com/create-site-to-site-ipsec-vpn-tunnel-openswan-linux.html

Comment: The how depends on you Linux distro and is typically well documented, i.e. seach on ipsec and your distro